# Extract model formula and results from ANN and Support Vector Regression

Tags: r, svm, data-analysis, neura

How can someone see the formula that has been produced by *ANN and Support Vector Regression in R studio*?

For example I know that in multi-variable regression you can get the coefficients and the equation `y=b0+b1*x1+b2*x2+...+bn*xn`. But what about `ANN` and `SVR`?

How can someone ***extract*** their formulas regarding multiple variables? What I had in mind was to make an excel spreadsheet with these parameters and insert values for the variables and get the predicted result.

I would appreciate any help.